# How to charge two 12V batteries in series with a 12V charger

Tags: battery-charging

I have setup the following circuit in my home. There is a logic circuit, (NodeMCU) which operates a relay, which causes it to activate the electromagnet.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f19ovk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All of the stuff here, except for the logic circuit is pretty much DIY, we made the electromagnet ourselves so can't provide a value on how much magnetic field it produces, however, it's just enough at 24V.
The two 12V batteries that you see there are batteries that were salvaged from old electrical scooters, combining them in series made the 24V we required, but to charge the circuit, we only have a 12V charger in our home.

Is there any way to charge those batteries without disconnecting anything? i.e., can we charge this system, while it's in operation? And when there is a power outage, it will continue to rely on the batteries?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: How much time would the batteries need to spend on charge? You could use a double pole relay to swap the charger between batteries, charging one at a time. But most likely the easiest solution would be to buy a second chager.

Comment: I don't have a specific time range for it to charge, i just want to the leave the batteries there as-is. I am considering the same option, along with all the advise given in the answer below. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct answer: No, it's not possible.

Let me further explain, as you said, the series connected batteries generate 24V voltage output. If your charger is 12V, the series connected batteries is going to create a voltage difference of 12V (which is 24V from batteries - 12V from charger) in the charger itself, which could result damaging the charge in case of no internal protection/cut-off circuit.

Solution 1: You could create a control circuit so when the charger is connected the batteries enter in parallel state with transistors and/or mosfets but would be a relative much more complex circuit design.

Solution 2: Change the charger to 24V instead, than you need to check how much current does the charger provide versus how much the system consumes (batteries charging + the electromagnectic) to see if the charger can support while the system is on.

Really important advise: when your using magnectic coils, you must place diodes in parallel to protect your source. The coils discharge currents can be really high, damaging all the circuit connected to it. So place a diode in parallel to the input of relay 1 and another to the "electromagnet" itself with reverse polarization. This means that the diodes cathode is connected to positive and anode to negative for both cases, like this image below to assist your implementation.

Just more advises: as you don't specified what the "electromagnet" really is, if it's acting like an inductor you need to set the maximum current, or the batteries could be shorted, resulting in permanent damage or even explosion. So add a resistor in series to limit the current going to the coil, show in the image as well.
Assuming your battery isn’t intelligent, if their voltages drop below certain level they can be permanent damaged. When working with rechargeable batteries, to protect them we need to place a cut-off controller, which basically is a control circuit that will automatically "disconnect" the batteries when they drop below a certain voltage level.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. The "electromagnet" here is just a janky electromagnet that we made at home for fun and then realized that we can actually use it for some home automation project with some salvaged scooter batteries that are lying around.

The batteries are not smart in anyway, and I will add the diodes as you have mentioned around the electromagnet, however, the relay is being triggered by 12V, I didn't understand how that could cause the logic circuit to be fried, there should be some gap in the middle of the relay itself to prevent this right?

Comment: Please let me know, if i should start this as a different question itself. I like your solution 2, i could just slap the charger in a NC relay & when the magnet activates, it will disconnect from the charger. This sounds like a "it will work for now" idea to me.

Comment: Related to your first question: activating the relay coil, in your case 12v, causes the coil to charge in form of magnectic field. When your controller stops providing 12v this causes a "perturbation" in the system making the coil discharge all that magnectic field opposed to the previously voltage applied, which can cause really high current spikes going from your relay to your controller.

Comment: The solution sounds "silly" but actually it isn't. It's just as simple as that! Now, of course the problem will not be solved with a single coil if you desire a robust solution. As a said, that is the hearth of the solution but a controller circuit (with cut-off) would have to be implement that would monitor each individual batteries and charger voltages to control that aditional relay. This controller circuit could be analog, digital, both.. There's a lot of options here

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I will add the diodes for safety, but will skip out on the controllers, and they are old salvaged batteries, and I don't have much care left for them.  I'll use it till it works and then send it off for re-cycling. This solution is also for a home automation project, not anything business related, so it's okay if i have to do some maintainence.

Comment: If he can apply a 24v charger across the batteries as a pair, could he not apply two separate 12v chargers - one charger across each battery?